# How to merge two list into a one with specific order?

Tags: flutter, dart

I've got 2 different lists with the same length as you can see below:

```
  List<String> qty = ["3 adet orta boy","4 yemek kaşığı","1 çay kaşığı","1 çay kaşığı","1 çay kaşığı","1 çay kaşığı","1 çay kaşığı"];
  
  List<String> name = ["patates","zeytinyağı","karabiber","toz kırmızı biber","kekik","tuz","sarımsak tozu"];
```

What I am trying to do is "qty[0] + name[0]", "qty[1] + name[1]" and so on.. The final output should look like this:

```
List<String> finalList = ["3 adet orta boy patates", "4 yemek kaşığı zeytinyağı", "1 çay kaşığı karabiber", "1 çay kaşığı toz kırmızı biber", "1 çay kaşığı kekik", "1 çay kaşığı tuz", "1 çay kaşığı sarımsak tozu"];
```

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using *for* loop:

```dart
var mergedLists = <String>[];
  for (var i = 0; i < qty.length; i++) {
    mergedLists.add('${qty[i]} ${name[i]}');
  }
}
```

Comment: Creating an extra `List` of indexes with `List.generate` seems rather gratuitous.  You could just create the indexes directly with `for (var i = 0; i < qty.length; i++) { ... }`.

Answer (score 0):

Since both list have the same length:

```
  List<String> qty = [
    "3 adet orta boy",
    "4 yemek kaşığı",
    "1 çay kaşığı",
    "1 çay kaşığı",
    "1 çay kaşığı",
    "1 çay kaşığı",
    "1 çay kaşığı"
  ];

  List<String> name = [
    "patates",
    "zeytinyağı",
    "karabiber",
    "toz kırmızı biber",
    "kekik",
    "tuz",
    "sarımsak tozu"
  ];
  
  List<String> finalList = [];

  for (int i = 0; i < qty.length; i++) {
    finalList.add(qty[i] + " " + name[i]);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

To append every element of the qty list with the corresponding element of the name list:

```
for(int i in qty.length){
  qty[i] = qty[i] + name[i];
}
```

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow because they don't explain how it solves the problem. Please edit your answer to explain what this code does and how it answers the question, so that it is useful to the OP as well as other users with similar issues.

Comment: I did. But OP clearly states: “What I am trying to do is "qty[0] + name[0]", "qty[1] + name[1]" and so on.. ”

Comment: The OP used that notation to explain their requirements, but your answer doesn't directly explain how to use it to answer the question. A better answer would the code in the question to solve the problem - without that, this is just the plain syntax for a standard for loop. This question was flagged by the community as low quality. Remember that Stack Overflow is for all users, and good answers are more likely to get upvoted.